# pandas, Find and keep consecutive rows - create a panel data

Tags: python, pandas-groupby, panel-data

I have a DataFrame like below:

```
df = {'time': [1999,2001,2002,2003,2007,1999,2000,2001,2003,2004],
      'id':['A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B'],
      'value':[0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.6,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

I want to create a panel dataset in the `id-time` level from it, which means, I want something like:

```
time id  value
0  2001  A    0.1
1  2002  A    0.1
2  2003  A    0.6
3  1999  B    0.2
4  2000  B    0.2
5  2001  B    0.2
```

Only consecutive rows of each `id` are left, I can finish this with just several lines in R,

```
df<-df %>% 
    mutate(time = as.integer(time)) %>% 
    group_by(gvkey, grp = cumsum(c(1, diff(time) != 1))) %>% 
    filter(n() >= consec_obs)
df<-df[,setdiff(colnames(df),c('grp'))]
```

in which `consec_obs` is the minimum of consecutive rows one wants to keep.

I searched for a while but couldn't find a solution, which surprised me a little bit as this is kind of basic econometric analysis manipulation, anyone knows how to do this with Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mimicking the R solution, I come up with a Python version on Sunday night, here it is:

```
# lag where two rows within each group are not conesecutive
df['diff'] = df.groupby('id')['time'].diff()!=1
# cumulative summation
df['cusm'] = df.groupby('id')['diff'].cumsum()
# group by 'id' and 'cusm', then select those rows which satisfy prespecified condition
df.loc[df.groupby(['id','cusm']).transform('count')['diff'] >=3].drop(['diff','cusm'],axis=1)
```

If this seems a liitle  hard to understand, try the code on a one line basis, you wiil get there.

Could it be possible to merge the first two line as one?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you. I'll try to explain each line as I move forward.

Import these 2 packages.

```
from itertools import groupby
import numpy as np
```

Your dataframe looks something like this:

```
>>>df = {'time': [1999,2001,2002,2003,2007,1999,2000,2001,2003,2004],
  'id':['A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B'],
  'value':[0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.6,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2]}

>>>df = pd.DataFrame(df)
>>>df

    id  time    value
0   A   1999    0.1
1   A   2001    0.1
2   A   2002    0.1
3   A   2003    0.1
4   A   2007    0.6
5   B   1999    0.2
6   B   2000    0.2
7   B   2001    0.2
8   B   2003    0.2
9   B   2004    0.2
```

First Step:
Find Unique IDs. This is how you do it:

```
>>>unique = np.unique(df.id.values).tolist()
>>>unique
['A', 'B']
```

Second Step:
For each ID, create a list of lists (I named it as Group). Each list inside the outer list contains consecutive numbers. To give clarity, I will take the print of the Group. It will group together a list of consecutive numbers.

Third Step:
After Grouping, Create a data frame for only those values where the length of Grouping is greater than 2. (I am assuming 2 because you did not consider B:2003 & B:2004 as a consecutive sequence.)

Here is how that works:

```
# Create an Empty dataframe. This is where you will keep appending peices of dataframes
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
# Now you would want to iterate over your unique IDs ie. 'A', 'B'.
for i in unique:
#Create an empty list called Group. Here you will append lists that contain consecutive numbers.
    groups = []
    #Create a data frame where ID is equal to current iterating ID
    df1 = df.loc[df['id'] == i]
    #The next 2 for loops (nested) will return group (a list of lists)
    for key, group in groupby(enumerate(df1.time.values), lambda ix : ix[0] - ix[1]):
        list1 = []
        for j in list(group):
            list1.append(j[1])
        groups.append(list1)
    # See how your group for current ID looks
    print(groups)
    # Iterate within the created group. See if group length is > 2. If yes, append to df2 (the empty data frame that you created earlier)
    for j in groups:
        if len(j) > 1:
            # you are concatenating 2 frames in the below code.
            df2 = pd.concat([df2,df.loc[(df['time'].isin(j)) & (df['id'] == i)]])
```

Voila

```
>>>> df2
    id  time    value
1   A   2001    0.1
2   A   2002    0.1
3   A   2003    0.1
5   B   1999    0.2
6   B   2000    0.2
7   B   2001    0.2
```